# html canvas stroke create thicker line

Tags: html, canvas, stroke

This is the first time I use stackoverflow to ask for help, so if there is anything I have done wrong please tell me. And I am not a native English speaker, so hope you understand my problem.

I was intend to create a webpage that can draw lines. There isn't any big issues. However, I realize that each time I use stroke() to draw a new lines, the previous lines become thicker. Can this problem be solved?

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="coord"></div>
<canvas id="Maintheme" height="800" width="1000"></canvas>
</body>
<script>
var canvas=document.getElementById("Maintheme");
var context=canvas.getContext('2d');
var coordinates;
var Xcoor;
var Ycoor;
var lineboolean=false;
canvas.width=window.innerWidth;
canvas.height=window.innerHeight;
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove',function(evt){
coordinates=evt.clientX+" "+evt.clientY;
Xcoor=evt.clientX;
Ycoor=evt.clientY;
document.getElementById("coord").innerHTML=coordinates;})
canvas.addEventListener('click',function(){
if (lineboolean==false){
context.moveTo(Xcoor,Ycoor);
lineboolean=true;
}
else{
context.lineTo(Xcoor,Ycoor);
context.stroke();
lineboolean=false;
}
})
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: You must begin each new set of path commands with context.beginPath(). Otherwise all the previous path commands since the last beginPath will be re-drawn along with newest commands.